# My Timeseries are shifting away from x axis in Dygraph

Tags: r-dygraphs, ggtimeseries

I have a dygraph with 2 dySeries. My data ranges from -50 to +90. When the dySeries with + values is added, the dySeries with - vlues is shifting above the x-axis. "drawAxesAtZero" in DyOption is not working. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.